# finding an average time based on unique entries in duplicate list

Tags: excel-formula

I have a large spreadsheet that list 138 different exams, each has its own time length. the spreadsheet has nearly 1300 entries.  As the list grows, the average time for each exam changes, obviously.

As I enter another exam (each with their own start time and exam length), I'd like a formula that will auto fill the "expected end time for this exam is:"

My spreadsheet has these column headings:

```
EXAM  | TOTAL EXAM TIME  | START TIME OF EXAM  |  LATEST END TIME FOR EXAM  |  ACTUAL END TIME OF EXAM  |  ACTUAL LENGTH OF EXAM ||  AVERAGE TIME FOR THIS EXAM  | GUESTIMATED END TIME BASED ON AVR TEST TIME FOR THIS EXAM.
```

The last entry is key because it helps determine how long we have to staff the exam center.

I have a sample spreadsheet if that would be helpful, I just wasn't sure how to upload it here.  EM me directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize some helper columns to build it dynamically for the future. I would get the data from the EXAM,TOTAL EXAM TIME, and START TIME OF EXAM columns.

Use an array to drag down in the first column of the helper columns:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5000, MATCH(0, COUNTIF(F$1:$F1, $A$2:$A$5000), 0),1),"")
```

`CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` this to make it an array and drag it way down. It will remove the duplicate exam names.

In the column next to it use `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5000,F2,$B$2:$B$5000)` to sum per each unique exam name and drag it down as well.

Then use `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$5000,F2)` in the next column to count the total exam time ever for each exam, drag down.

Then use `=G2/H2` to get the average time for each exam, drag it.

With these 4 columns you now have a 4 column table.

In the `GUESSTIMATED END TIME BASED ON AVR TEST TIME FOR THIS EXAM` column, use `=C2+VLOOKUP(A2,F:I,4,FALSE)` to add the average time to the start time. A2 is the exam name, F:I is the table of columns you created, 4 is the 4th column,C2 is the start time.

You can drag all of these down in their respective columns.

I have added a picture to show the layout but it can be tweaked for your purposes.

This would be a dynamic solution for you.

Hope it works well! Feel free to ask for more explanation on it if needed.

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nFp.jpg)